# How do I say: I'm not afraid of you

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm not sure if one uses the adjective or verb of FEAR in this case

What I have is the following:

> EGO DE TE NON METUO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not aware that you could use *de* with metuere, but I looked it up and you can. However, it means "about" in that case, and you might want to use just an accusative *te*.

You don't need to use *ego* in this sentence, unless you want to say something like "*I'm* not afraid of you"

Also, you might want to consider using *timere* or *metuere* depending on the context of your sentence. *Timere* means "to fear" or "to be afraid of" emotionally, due to external factors, while *metuere* means "to fear" or "be afraid of" due to reflection or meditation, the fear of the evil itself. The opposite of *timere* is *fido*, "trust", while the opposite of *metuere* is "spero", "hope".

Overall, I'd either say "Te non metuo" or "Te non timeo"

Comment: We **must** use the accusative because *de te metuo* means "I am afraid **for** you" (i.e., I fear something untoward will happen to you).